# C# Как скачать natives/ для майнкрафта

Tags: java, c#, minecraft

Я пишу свой лаунчер Майнкрафта. Мне нужны все библиотеки Майнкрафта (dll файлы, LWJGL, OpenAL и другие). Сейчас на официальном сайте LWJGL есть только версии 3.0+, а версии 2.x.x отсутствуют. Примерно тоже самое и с другими библиотеками. Сейчас у меня страдает крашится каждая версия. И крашится не майн, а джава с ошибкой EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION. Прочитав логи, проблема была вызвана LWJGL.dll (я пытался подобрать версию).

Comment: Добавил метку java, возможно что коллеги подскажут. А вообще вопрос по поиску библиотек не очень тематичен для so. Возможно, правда, что в комментариях и подскажут что-то дельное.

Comment: github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl/releases это подойдет?